# How do I send data from client to server using LiteNetLib

Tags: c#, networking, litenetlib

I started with the example client and server from [here](https://github.com/RevenantX/LiteNetLib#usage-samples) and modified the client to send a response back to the server... which never arrives. What am I doing wrong? How do I do this?

Server:

```
using LiteNetLib;
using LiteNetLib.Utils;

Console.WriteLine("=== Server ===");
EventBasedNetListener listener = new EventBasedNetListener();
NetManager server = new NetManager(listener);
server.Start(9050);

listener.ConnectionRequestEvent += request => {
    if (server.ConnectedPeersCount < 10 /* max connections */)
        request.AcceptIfKey("SomeConnectionKey");
    else
        request.Reject();
};

listener.PeerConnectedEvent += peer => {
    Console.WriteLine("We got connection: {0}", peer.EndPoint); // Show peer ip
    NetDataWriter writer = new NetDataWriter();                 // Create writer class
    writer.Put("Hello client!");                                // Put some string
    peer.Send(writer, DeliveryMethod.ReliableOrdered);             // Send with reliability
};

listener.NetworkReceiveEvent += (fromPeer, dataReader, deliveryMethod) => {
    Console.WriteLine("We got: {0}", dataReader.GetString(100 /* max length of string */));
    dataReader.Recycle();
};

while (!Console.KeyAvailable) {
    server.PollEvents();
    Thread.Sleep(15);
}

server.Stop();
```

Client:

```
using LiteNetLib;
using LiteNetLib.Utils;

Console.WriteLine("=== Client ===");
EventBasedNetListener listener = new EventBasedNetListener();
NetManager client = new NetManager(listener);
client.Start();
var serverPeer = client.Connect("localhost", 9050, "SomeConnectionKey");

listener.NetworkReceiveEvent += (fromPeer, dataReader, deliveryMethod) => {
    Console.WriteLine("We got: {0}", dataReader.GetString(100 /* max length of string */));
    dataReader.Recycle();
};

NetDataWriter writer = new NetDataWriter();                 // Create writer class
writer.Put("Hello server!");                                // Put some string
serverPeer.Send(writer, DeliveryMethod.ReliableOrdered);    // Send with reliability

while (!Console.KeyAvailable) {
    client.PollEvents();
    Thread.Sleep(15);
}

client.Stop();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `client.SendUnconnectedMessage(packet,peer.EndPoint)` to send message to a fix endpoint - in your case the endpoint is the server.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks I totally gave up on this side project (and in writing a multiplayer game in general) but I'll give it a try.